# Search by product name only Magento ver. 1.9.2.4

Tags: magento-1.9, search, advanced-search

How to get search by product name only magento.

Comment: Magento default search is not very good, you can use some third party search extensions and apply your condition as your wish.

Comment: can u suggest me extension?

Comment: http://start.searchanise.com/       magento extension also available for this one.

Answer (score 2):

1. Login to admin panel
2. Go to catalog > attributes > manage attributes > search as product_name at attribute code
3. Open that attribute and select properties
4. Set as Use in advanced search to Yes
5. Set as Use in quick search to Yes
6. Clear cache